# How to get wordpress posts by taxonomy terms. XML-RPC

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

How to get wordpress posts by taxonomy terms using XML-RPC?
For example I want to get all posts tagged by 2014 tag.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you cannot do this.  You will need to build your own method to be used within XML-RPC in order to achieve this.

The [documentation on extending the XML-RPC API on the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending) has some good examples of how to build your own method.